# JAVA PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl-certificate, talend, keytool, sslhandshakeexception, pkix

I have Talend Big Data application which is I want to run a job. It contains "tREST" component that supposed to fetch REST API endpoint. All is fine when I'm using Postman, I get all the results that I want.

But when I executed the job, it gives me this error.

```
Starting job test_api at 14:28 08/03/2022.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3641
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tREST_1 (test_api)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX 
path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
find valid certification path to requested target at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.j ava:155) 
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
at ace.test_api_0_1.test_api.tREST_1Process(test_api.java:983)
at ace.test_api_0_1.test_api.runJobInTOS(test_api.java:1674)
at ace.test_api_0_1.test_api.main(test_api.java:1436)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification 
path to requested target`
```

I already run the troubleshoot as mentioned in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524960
but I believe I only save the certification as in global, not in the right path. Question is how can I store it in Talend or java path?

Comment: Can you go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs; and check that the path Talend is using is the one you installed the certificate into ?

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar is the cert must be locate inside bin folder? My local path is "C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot"

Comment: There should be a "jre" folder under jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot; the certificate needs to be installed from there. So run keytool from jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\jre\bin, and point it to the keystore in jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\jre\lib\security\cacerts. Can you try that?